# What is necessary to work with inset face mode?

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view

I'm trying to inset another face near the center of this plate. After pressing <kbd>I</kbd> key the inset information appears on top of the screen but there is no dotted circle showing the preview before confirming and no additional vertices are created after confirming.

I have tried to reset scale using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>A</kbd> in Edit mode and Object mode as other answers suggests but it didn't work. Also closing blender doesn't seem to solve the problem.

I have 3rd mouse button emulation enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your image I can see that you are using Vertex Select. In this case, activate Face Select.

[image]

[Inset Faces](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/face/inset_faces.html) is a Face Tool. It needs you to select all the vertices/edges that make up a face.

You can use it via Vertex Select (or Edge Select) as well, however, you need to select the central vertex to select the tris (triangles or faces with 3 vertices).

[image]

Comment: Are there some rules related to when it's possible to inset face with vertex? I have selected the vertices of the face I want to edit until now.

Comment: I updated my answer with a new gif to illustrate. Please take a look.